# Maxima asks: "positive, negative, zero ?" How to see all at once

Tags: maxima

Maxima often asks  `positive, negative, zero ?` while solving ODE. Is there a way to see all of them at once ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Load the `noninteractive` package, which comes bundled with recent Maxima versions, before solving the ODE.

You can load it with:

```
load(noninteractive);
```